# Generated IDL from java-Interface with rmic generates an Error

Tags: java, c++, corba, idl, rmic

I am working in a project, were we write a Java RMI-IIOP Server and da CORBA-C++ client. We generate the IDL from our Java-Interface with rmic -idl. But I think something is wrong in our Interface, because when we compile the generated idl, we got following error:

```
./WishlistInterface.idl:33: java/io/FileNotFoundEx.idl: No such file or directory
./WishlistInterface.idl:102: java/util/ArrayList.idl: No such file or directory
./WishlistInterface.idl:103: java/io/File.idl: No such file or directory
./WishlistInterface.idl:80: scoped name '::java::io::FileNotFoundEx' not defined
```

And this is our Interface:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface WishlistInterface extends java.rmi.Remote {

public int secureLogin(String username, long checksum) throws RemoteException;
public ArrayList<Wish> getUnreceivedWishes(String username)throws RemoteException;
public void createWishlist(String wishlistTitle) throws RemoteException;          
public File downloadWishlist(String wishlistTitle, String username) throws FileNotFoundException, RemoteException;           
public void logout(String username) throws RemoteException;   
}
```

Has anyone an idea, what exactly is wrong?
Thx!

Comment: Looks like the generated namespace parts are translated into directories for the corresponding `#include` directory parts. Are those headers to be found in these directories? If yes, you might need to provide an appropriate `-I` option when compiling the DLL.

Comment: Yes, the missing idl are in these directories! Sounds like I have to look into the documentation of rmic, if there ist such similar -I parameter?!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry, I'm not experienced with rmic.

Comment: Ok! After a frustrating day, of researching about the rmic, I still have not an answer or idea... Maybe I write a IDL by myself and compile it to java with idlj-Compiler